Пишу про текстА или пишу про текстЫ?
Как правильно, скажите, пожалуйста?

а почему ты пишешь "текста"

Так как правильно?

https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82?ysclid=lx6fbp3kjz412240507

Выбор А/Ы в форме И.п. мн. числа – вечная проблема.  Посмотреть в словаре можно, но обычно не только называют форму, но объясняют выбор. И вот бы хотелось услышать, как выбирать. Для сравнения: пост (с разной семантикой), рост, торт – торты, где часто делается ошибка. штормы (нейтр.) и шторма (разг.)  https://russkij.shkolkovo.net/catalog/morfologicheskie_oshibki/mnozhestvennoe_chislo/page-3

ОТВЕТ
Правильно: пишу (про что?) про тексты.
Форма В.п. мн. числа для неодуш. сущ. тексты совпадает с формой И.п. мн. числа.

Существительное  текст имеет основное и единственное окончание Ы в форме И.п. мн. числа:  текст — тексты.  Вариантов нет, что определяется на слух.

В  словарях нет пометок для форм мн. числа (указано окончание  А  Р.п. ед. числа). Русский орфографический словарь: текст, -а. Например: нет подходящего текста.

Для сравнения  (русский орфографический словарь)

рост2, -а, мн. -а, -ов (длина одежды).  Указано мн. число для слова в этом значении, например: разные ростА одежды.
дом, -а, предл. в доме и (разг.) в дому, на доме и (дома) на дому, мн. -а, -ов;
Если написание окончаний совпадает (нет дома, большие дома), то указаны обе формы (-а для ед. и мн. числа).
